# New Drupal modules not showing

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have been trying to install new modules on a site I inherited but I can not get them to show up in the module list.  I have tried installing them through ftp and the "Install new module" link.  The site is running on Drupal 7.31 and PHP 5.3.3.  PHP Safemode is off.  I have tried changing the permission on /sites/all/modules and all subfolders to 755.  I have tried running cron and clearing the cache.  There are a lot of FTP accounts, I am not sure which one the site was setup with but I believe this doesn't matter because Safemode is off.

What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you running?
This can sound like a stupid question, but, are you sure that the ftp accounts that you are using correspond to the live site?
If you're running linux, you have to confirm the owner of the site files.
safe_mode is deprecated in php 5.3.
Maybe you can try to set the permissions to 777 temporarily and see what happens.

Comment: It is CentOS.  I went into the Plesk file manager and poked around.  I noticed that both of the modules that I had been testing were not showing in the file manager.  I tried uploading them in the file manager and they showed up in Drupal!  I would guess this would indicate an ownership issue?  Thanks for your help!